# Execution Plan- executedPlan in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I was going over to UDF disadvantages and came across scala code which shows how using inbuilt functions can improve the performance. To show the difference, an author has used .queryExecution.executedPlan method and it shows pushed filters and partition filter details in the plan. However same details I wanted to see in pyspark code but still  not able to find the method which can show  the same details.

In the pyspark code I have used new_df.explain(True) menthod and new_df._jdf.queryExecution().toString() to get the details but unable to get the required details in the plan. Can someone please point me to right direction ?

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

data = [("jose", 1), ("li", 2), ("liz", 3)]
source_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["name", "age"])

## with UDF ##
def with_greeting(x):
  if x == "jose":
    return True
with_greeting= udf(with_greeting,BooleanType())

new_df = source_df.where(with_greeting(source_df.age))
new_df._jdf.queryExecution().toString() 
##new_df.explain(True)


##With out UDF##
new_df = source_df.filter(source_df.name=="jose")
##new_df.explain(True)
new_df._jdf.queryExecution().toString()
##new_df._jdf.executedPlan().toString()
```

I do not see the details of pushed filters and anywhere it indicates that it applies the filter while reading it the way it was shown to scala ,like Inmemoryfileindex pushedfilter=[details] ?``

Comment: import pprint
pprint.pprint(new_df._jdf.queryExecution().simpleString())

Comment: I think it gives me the same plan , I can not see whether it was filtered during the read or after here is your code execution result, with UDF : '== Physical Plan ==\n'
 '*(2) Project [name#10, age#11L]\n'
 '+- *(2) Filter pythonUDF0#15: boolean\n'
 '   +- BatchEvalPython [with_greeting(age#11L)], [pythonUDF0#15]\n'
 '      +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[name#10,age#11L]') With OUT UDF: ('== Physical Plan ==\n'
 '*(1) Filter (isnotnull(name#6) && (name#6 = jose))\n'
 '+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[name#6,age#7L]')